# AS3: Math-related - Constructing Equilateral Triangle

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, math

I am trying to construct an equilateral triangle with the following code, but I am not seeing what I would expect to.
I would expect to see a triangle drawn to the stage, but I don't see one.
I think there must be something wrong in terms of the location of the tri sprite on the screen.

```
public class test_drawing_triangle extends Sprite
{
    public function test_drawing_triangle()
    {
        var tri:Sprite = new Sprite;    
        var nextx:int;
        var nexty:int;
        var prevx:int;
        var prevy:int;
        var angle:Number;
        var radius:Number;
        var deg:int;
        var i:int;

        radius = 10;
       // tri.x = stage.stageWidth / 2;
        tri.y = 50;

        tri.graphics.clear();
        tri.graphics.beginFill(0x000000, 0.5);
        tri.graphics.moveTo(0,0);

        for(deg = 0; deg < 360; deg += 120)
        {
            angle = deg * Math.PI / 180;
            nextx = Math.cos(angle) * radius;
            nexty = Math.sin(angle) * radius;
            tri.graphics.lineTo(nextx, nexty);
        }
        tri.graphics.endFill();
        addChild(tri);
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:**

I can now see the triangle but it is not filled in.
It seems to have the generally-correct shape, but I would expect for it be 3 sided, rather than 4.
If anyone could take a sec to compile this and look at what I am describing it would really help.

Comment: "It doesn't work" isn't a very helpful description. Can you describe more precisely what the problem you're having is?

Comment: I've updated my question, although I must say that I never stated "it doesn't work".  That's not a very useful critique either.

Comment: Try adjusting your colour cordinates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understand what you're trying to do, but if you want to have the circles at the corners of the triangle. than you need to change the

> tri.graphics.drawCircle(0, 0, 2);

to

> tri.graphics.drawCircle(nextx, nexty, 2);

drawCircle takes absolute x,y and doesn't care about the moveTo

EDIT - use this code in place of your loop

```
deg = 30;
angle = (deg * Math.PI) / 180.0;
nextx = Math.cos(angle) * radius;
nexty = Math.sin(angle) * radius;
(tri.graphics as Graphics).moveTo(nextx, nexty);
for(deg = 150; deg < 420; deg += 120)
{
 angle = (deg * Math.PI) / 180.0;
 nextx = Math.cos(angle) * radius;
 nexty = Math.sin(angle) * radius;   
 (tri.graphics as Graphics).lineTo(nextx, nexty);     
}
```

Comment: wow! totally worked!  how come you need to use 'as Graphics'?  I'll certainly look into it in the docs; but I haven't seen this syntax being used before.

Comment: Sorry for the mess, you don't really need to, I just needed to check something in the process, and left it in. Going to sleep now, it's past midnight :)

Comment: FYI, using the as keyword to typecast is less efficient when compared to something like: Graphics(tri.graphics) when you know that the object you are typecasting will actually be that type (ie: as performs checking to determine if it can do the cast before doing it, the method I mention just casts without a check).

Answer (score 0):

This code looks like its drawing three circles centered on the points of your triangle. If that's the case, then replace

```
tri.graphics.moveTo(nextx, nexty);  
tri.graphics.drawCircle(0, 0, 2);
```

with

```
tri.graphics.lineTo(nextx, nexty);
```

If that's not the case, please specify what it is you are seeing so we might have a better idea of what's gone wrong.

Comment: For right now I am not seeing _anything_.
There are a couple problems... one is that the image is not drawn where i would expect it to be.  The lines/dots are inconsequential; its' the coordinates being right that I am after.  Basically I want the anchor (xy) to be in the middle of the triangle, pointing upward as an arrow would...  I've altered my code in case that helps.

Comment: OK; I have updated my code, please see above.  I can see a triangle being drawn but it looks as if the triangle is not completely filled in.  I took your advice and used the lineTo(nextx, nexty) but it seems as though I am not starting off in the correct position when I call beginFill(0x000000, 0.5).

Answer (score 0):

Is there are particular reason why you are using angles to draw the triangle?

If I were to do this, I'd simply hard code a unit sized equilateral triangle (defined as three 3d points) once and then use scale and translation operations to put it in the correct size and position.

Comment: one reason is that I wanted to learn how to do it; another would be that now I have the points; so I _can_ hardcode it;  Ultimately one might want a shape like this to morph between states or be more versatile depending on the arguments/properties.  I do see your point if you'd only want a triangle.  But... you can scale/translate/transform with this as well.